# Why Obj.*A is out of scope?

Tags: c++, pointers

Here is part of my class `assign_obj`, constructor and operator that I want to print the object.
When trying to compile operator I am getting error :

```
error: 'A' was not declared in this scope for(assign_obj::item anItem : obj.*A){
```

Why is that?
If I try `obj.A` instead, I get error for the forloop as C++ can not loop a pointer of dynamic array.

```
class assign_obj{
    private:
        
        struct item{
            char value;
            int count;
        };
        item * A; //pointer A pointing to something of type Item
        int size;
    public:
        assign_obj();
        assign_obj(std::string);
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream & out, assign_obj & obj);
```

```
//Constructor
assign_obj::assign_obj(string aString){
    size = aString.size();
    A = new item[size];

    item myItem;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        myItem = {(char)toupper(aString[i]), 1};
        A[i] = myItem;
    }
}
```

```
// Print operator
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream & out, assign_obj & obj){
    out <<"[ ";
    for(assign_obj::item anItem : obj.*A){
        out << anItem.value;
        out << ":";
        out << anItem.count;
        out << " ";
    }
    out <<"]";
    return out;
}
```

Comment: `obj.A` is the correct syntax to access the `A` member of `obj`. But in c++ it recomended to use `std::vector` instead of raw C arrays. This will enable you also to use a range based loop.

Comment: `.*` is an operator with two characters, just like `+=`. It's not two separate operators; that would be `. *`, with a space between them. `.*` expects a reference to an object on its left-hand side, and a pointer-to-member on its right-hand side. `A` is not a pointer-to-member, so the code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a for loop that way for a dynamically allocated array. You can use a plain old for loop for your plain old array.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream & out, assign_obj & obj){
    out <<"[ ";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < obj.size; i++) {
        out << obj.A[i].value << ":"
            << obj.A[i].count << " ";
    }
    out <<"]";
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Well, you can (i.e., must) use a plain old for loop for your plain old *pointer* pointing to the first element in your plain old array. You *can* (and should) use a range based for loop for your plain old array, but the type requires compile-time knowledge of its size.

Answer (score 2):

In c++ it is usually recomended to use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), instead of raw c arrays.

You need to add:

```
#include <vector>
```

Then your member will be:

```
std::vector<item> A;
```

Allocating the items in `assign_obj::assign_obj` is done like this:

```
A.resize(size);
```

Finally your `operator<<` will be:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream & out, assign_obj & obj){
    out <<"[ ";
//-----------------------vvvvvvv----------vvvvv--
    for(assign_obj::item const & anItem : obj.A){
        out << anItem.value;
        out << ":";
        out << anItem.count;
        out << " ";
    }
    out <<"]";
    return out;
}
```

Notes:

1. Accessing the `A` member of `obj` is done with `obj.A`, **not** `obj.*A`.
2. Travresing the vector is done with a `const&` to avoid copy.